# Power consumption in voltage detector

Tags: cmos, power-consumption, voltage-detector

I am quite new in embedded system and circuit design. I have designed a system in which I have to add voltage detectors. I need to find the accurate power that the detector can consume in each cycle depending upon the value of voltage provided. 
Can anyone please guide me how to get the value of current draw in the detector when the voltage provided is between 1.8-3.6 volts.

Following is the link to datasheet.
https://www.rohm.com/datasheet/BU4811FVE/bu48xxg-e

[image]

Comment: The data sheet says the device uses max 0.55uA. The open drain will not 'use' any current from the supply and the CMOS driver version depends on what you are trying to source/sink at the output. So tell us more how you plan to connect it.

Answer (score 1):

Supply current is given by datasheet:

[image]

If you use the open-drain output, you'll need to add the pullup resistor current (only when output is low).

If you use the CMOS output, which is push-pull so it doesn't require a pullup, you'll need to add any current drawn by whatever circuit is connected to the output. If this is the input of a CMOS chip, check its datasheet for input leakage current. This will probably be so tiny it will be safe to neglect it. Now, if you want to light a LED with the output, that's different.